# Finding area of a region in terms of a variable

Tags: calculus, area

The curves $y=mx$ and $y=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ enclose a region for $0<m<1$. Find the area of a region in terms of only m. The integral I set up is the following $$A=2\int_{a}^{0}\left(mx-\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right)dx=ma^2+\ln|a^2+1|$$
The answer I sholuld get is $A=m-\ln|m-1|$.How do I get there ? Can I express $a$ in terms of $m$ ?

Comment: do you have any ideas after seeing this? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%2F(x%5E2%2B1)+and+x%2F2+from+-2+to+2

Comment: What is $a$? Intersection point of these two functions can be expressed in terms of $m$. Replace $a$ with that and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The points of intersection 
are the roots of 
\begin{align} 
\frac{x}{x^2+1}-mx&=0
,
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
x&=0,\ \pm \sqrt{\frac1m-1}
.
\end{align}

Since $m<1$, the line $y=mx$ is below
the curve $\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ for 
$x\in(0,\sqrt{\frac1m-1})$,
hence the area is

\begin{align} 
A&=
2\,\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac1m-1}}
\left(
\frac{x}{x^2+1}-mx 
\right)\,dx 
\\
&=\left.
2\,\left(\tfrac12\ln(x^2+1) 
-\tfrac12\,m x^2
\right)\right|_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac1m-1}}
\\
&=m-1-\ln m
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Solvingt the equation $$mx=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$ we get
$$x=0$$ or $$x=\pm \frac{\sqrt{1-m}}{m}$$ so we get
$$A=2\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{1-m}{m}}}mx-\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx$$